# ggplot2 with factor variable y axis and removed whitespace

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot like the one below, with a factor variable on the y-axis.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

MA <- c("A", "B", "C")

dfr <- data.frame(
  name        = factor(MA, levels = MA),
  start       = 1:3,
  end         = 3:5,
  prozent     = c(1,0.5,0.75)
)
mdfr <- melt(dfr, measure.vars = c("start", "end"))

ggplot(mdfr, aes(value, name)) + geom_line(aes(size = prozent)) + scale_size_area()
```

[image]

I want to remove the whitespace (or, in default ggplot2, "greyspace") between the horizontal lines so that they touch each other.

Comment: Vertical dodging via `ggstance::position_dodgev` might have potential here.  You lose your `name` labels on the axis, though.  Depending on what you want your final result to be, that could be fine as these labels get quite squished when using `expand`, anyway, and adding other text labels might be as/more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do as follows:

```
ggplot(mdfr, aes(value, name)) +
  geom_line(aes(size = prozent)) +
  scale_size_area() +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(7, 0))
```

Comment: I think this is not a general solution. If you resize your plot you will still see "greyspaces".

Comment: For the moment I am happy that there is no more "greyspace" *between* the lines, at least with some fudging depending on the size of the plot. That said, if it were possible to also reduce the now increased greyspace above and below the lines, that would be great!

Comment: @Lstat not general indeed, but I think its difficult to manipulate the "grayspace" for a factor based `y-grid`. Otherwise you could just set a `limit()`. Do you happen to know other ways of doing this?

Comment: @AK88 Unfortunately not. I looked at grobs but still cannot find the right way...

Comment: @ChristophHanck That's what expand does - it puts "greyspaces" above and below the lines and squeezes them so there is not space in between.